# Python: pad floating point number with zeroes

Tags: python

How to pad with zeroes double numbers up to specified length?

```
printf "{:.3}".format(0.12) # Doesn't pad
```

I want to get

```
0.120
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need a `f` after `3`:

```
In [19]: "{:.3f}".format(0.12)
Out[19]: '0.120'
```

In case of floats if you don't specify any type then it uses `'g'` by default.

```
In [27]: "{:.20}".format(0.12)
Out[27]: '0.11999999999999999556'

In [28]: "{:.20g}".format(0.12)
Out[28]: '0.11999999999999999556'
```

Documentation [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec).

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with a format string

```
print('%.3f' % 0.12)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a [type specifier](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting):

```
>>> print "{:.3f}".format(0.12)
0.120
```